# Choosing $a$ such that equation $f(x, a)=g(x)$ has only one solution with respect to $x$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x, a)$ and $g(x)$ are given functions. We want to find all values of $a$ such that equation $f(x, a)-g(x)=0$ has only one solution with respect to $x$.

For example:

> $a \cdot \log_{a}x=x$

or

> $ax^4 - e^x=0$

Comment: Note that if $\partial f/\partial x - g'(x)$ does not vanish for any $x$, there will be no more than one solution for $f(x,a) = g(x)$.  This would not guarantee that any solutions actually exist, though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Clever! But if this is because of existence and uniqueness, shouldn't you check $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neat question! For the second, we have the first condition, that $f=0$ for some pair $(x,a)$
or
$$
a=\frac{e^x}{x^4}
$$
Noting that if $x=0$ we don't have any solutions at all.

Then we use a tangency condition of the two curves to guarantee uniqueness, getting a system of two equations in two unknowns, i.e.
$$
f'(x)=0\Rightarrow a=\frac{e^x}{4x^3} 
$$

Combining:
$$
x=4,\\
a=\frac{e^4}{4^4}
$$

For the first equation, use that $$\log_a x =\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}$$
and the same logic as above to get the system
$$
a\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}=x\\
\frac{a}{\ln a}=x\\
\Rightarrow \ln x=1\Rightarrow x=e\Rightarrow a=e
$$
with a's value by inspection.